# Heroku CLI doesn't work with Git Bash -- keeps looking for Ruby in the current directory

Tags: ruby, git, bash, heroku

So if I'm on `Desktop/code`

```
Ka@KA ~/Desktop/code
$ heroku console
/c/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/bin/heroku: line 4: /c/Users/Ka/Desktop/code/ruby: No such file or directory
/c/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/bin/heroku: line 4: exec: /c/Users/Ka/Desktop/code/ruby: cannot execute: No such file or directory
```

It'll look for ruby in `Desktop/code`

If I'm on any path, it'll look for Ruby on that path. Why is it doing that?

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error. I figured out that I had both the old version of the CLI (Heroku Toolbelt) and the new one. I uninstalled both and did a clean install of the Heroku CLI (I guess uninstalling the toolbelt is enough though), and now it works.
Maybe it can help somone.

Comment: I haven't used Heroku in a long time; can't confirm correct or not.